# Creating random points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, random

Has anyone else had any issues using the random points tool in QGIS?

When I try using it I'm selecting the option to use a value input field. The tool starts but then freezes once it gets to the 10% processing level as indicated by the status bar. Is this a known bug?

Comment: How many points are you trying to generate?  Are you making a shapefile?  Have you let the process run even though the status bar may not be incrementing?

Comment: Just generated 500 random points, worked fine although took a while on 55%.